# How to display the new image uploaded in cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have my image control like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetProfileImage", "Controller", new { id = Model.DocId})"
```

Action

```
public FileResult GetProfileImage(int id)
{
    var usr = new Whatever();
    byte[] barrImg = usr.GetProfilePhoto(id);
    return File(barrImg, "image/png");
}
```

My save method is like this:

```
function SavePhotoToDb() {
                var json;
                var data;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Example/SaveProfilePhoto",
                    data: new FormData($("#form0").get(0)),
                    dataType: "html",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: saveItemCompleted(data),
                    error: saveItemFailed
                });
            }

        function saveItemCompleted(data) {
               //showing success notification;
               // what else I have to do here to display the new image
    }
```

this is working fine when the page is loaded with alreay profile photo uploaded.
But when a upoad a new photo it should display the new photo, but its not hitting the GetProfileImage() action when I upload a new photo and even when i delete the photo its getting deleted from sql server but page still shows the photo..

What should I do when I upload a new photo,so that new photo will be displayed and what should i do when I delete the photo so that it will not display the photo since i have deleted the photo.

Comment: Try reloading the page?

Comment: I am just displaying the success notification like this:    ShowSuccess("Upload was Successful");      I am not getting what code to write so that new image will be displayed after upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `id` to `img` tag

```
 <img id="myimage" src="@Url.Action("GetProfileImage", "Controller", new { id = Model.DocId})"
```

In JS function

```
 function saveItemCompleted(data) {
     //Force to reloaded image
     var image = new Image();
     image.src = $("#myimage").attr("src") + "?_=" + (new Date().getTime()) ;
     $("#myimage").attr("src", image.src) 
 }
```